# Serializing object to JSON and getting format of 

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

What C-sharp type can I serialize to get JSON object with format "name":[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

If serialize array like this
public int[,] data = {{23,21,10},{45,43,50},{23,21,90}};
it gives format of
"data":[23,21,10,45,43,50,23,21,90]

Or more generally, is there some list where i can find what type is serialized in which format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As specified on MSDN,

> A multidimensional array is serialized as a one-dimensional array, and you should use it as a flat array.

As specified by Phil.Wheeler, this code does what you want:

```
List<int[]> name = new List<int[]>(){ new int[]{ 23, 21, 10 }, new int[]{ 45, 43, 50 }, new int[]{ 23, 21, 90 } }; 

string ser = (new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(name);
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just serialise a `List<ArrayList>` or even `List<int[]>`, couldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

Serialize an array of arrays?